# <algorithm> won't compile on Dev C++ compiler

Tags: templates, compiler-construction, linker-errors, dev-c++, stl-algorithm

I am trying to port some code using the Dev_C++ 4.9.9.2 compiler and I cannot get it to recognise the standard algorithm template as in

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Whenever I attempt to compile I get numerous error messages, the majority saying "template with C linkage." What am I doing wrong? Is there some setting I need to adjust on the compiler.

Tech Specs - I am running the compiler on Windows XP SP3 on Oracle VirtualBox, which in turn is on a Ubuntu 10.10 AMD64 host machine.

Comment: what is the original code language? C? you might need to put the #endif at the end maybe....been a while since I have looked at C++. Also, you don't have another curly brace....

Comment: Minor point: the `#include <algorithm>` will fail if it's not a C++ environment anyway. As a result, there is little point in using `#ifdef __cplusplus` guards around the `extern "C" {`

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to have been given in an answer that has now been deleted: move the includes outside the extern "C" { braces

```
using namespace std ;
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

This compiles without error messages.